# How to upload multiple files in uploadcare?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadcare

This is [uploadcare](http://uploadcare.com) question.

How to upload multiple files using uploadcare js api ?

I have this code but no luck

```
for (var x = 0; x < document.getElementById('files').files.length; x++) {          
    console.log(x);
    console.log(document.getElementById('files').files[x]);
    uploadcare.filesFrom('object', document.getElementById('files').files[x]);
}
```

Comment: It works with `fileFrom` but not `filesFrom`. Anyone can explain?  Thanks in adv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `uploadcare.fileFrom` and `uploadcare.filesFrom` is the first takes one initial object and returns exactly one uploadcare file, the second takes array of objects and returns array of uploadcare files. So you do not need to iterate `files` to transmit it in `filesFrom`.

```
var uploads = uploadcare.filesFrom('object', document.getElementById('files').files);
console.log(uploads);
```

Please, look at live example http://jsbin.com/zayuz/1/watch?html,js,output